# Not interrupting workflow by eventcalls

Tags: c#, visual-studio, events

i want to know a little bit more about how events actually work.

My goal: I want to implement a kind of scheduling. I have a set of operation which have to be done at different locations. In my scheduling process I want to look at the certain states of the operations and assign them to there location. How the actual schedling works is actually not important. At certain points in the process an event is called, when a new operation gets created or if an operation is done for example. Everytime this event gets called I run my scheduling algorithm, and look for new assignments.

My problem: I do not know how these Events actually affect my workflow. At certain point an operation A is at the beginning of my scheduliing at the state (running) and at a later point at the state (finished) which makes the scheduling pretty hard. I do not want the states to switch during this process. I think the events are causing the problem and now to find a solution I want to understand more about those events. How does this work?

I heard something like, if an event is called, my current process is been interrupted, the event is been processed, and then my current process will continue. Is this the way they work?

And if so how does the following szenario look like:
run schedule() > interrupt(new Operation)
This event call now calls again schedule() > run schedule()(2)

Does now at first schedule()(2) will finish which is called in the event, then the event will finish and then the original schedule()?

And besides that, is there a good way to handle such workflow with events? a standard procedure or something? Or are the events no problem there and I have somewhere else a problem?

Can I tell to progam not to interrupt this workflow? Should I run the schedule() in a thread on it's own?

Thank you for your time

Simplified version of the code:

```
public void schedule()
{
  //Do the scheduling process (1)
  if (this.scheduleChanged != null)
  {
     this.scheduleChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
  }
  //Show debuginformation (3)
}  

//Gets called in schedule after all operations are assigned to a location
public void EndOfScheduleEvent()
{
  //Let operations run on assigned locations
  //switch state of operation to running (2)
}

//When an operation is finished it causes an event, which calls this method
//This method calls again the schedule() method for reschedule
public void endOfOperationEvent()
{
  //change state of operation to pause
  schedule();
}
```

I print out a lot for debugging. And What I found is that an operation which starts at the state (ready) at (1) in code. Now I trigger the event scheduleChanged(). What I want know is, that the method schedule() proceeds. so that I will have for that operation on (3) in code the state (ready). But what happens is, that the event gets called directly, so my current process gets interrupted. So we are now in the method EndOfScheduleEvent(), whch changes the state of my operation to (running) (2) in code. and then proceeds again in my schedule() method, where my output in (3) is (running) for my operation.

Comment: Could post some of your code, more specifically where you're running into your problem? Also, no, events do no interrupt your current process, they will get added to the queue and be processed once it's their turn

Comment: And, if you want to learn more about events (and delegates) I highly recommend [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)'s article about it [here](https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Events)

Comment: Windows is a multi-process operating system that does task switching and processes events.  The Windows Timer Tick Event does the Task switching and calls Events.   Windows has an Event chain (linked list) of Events that the drivers install.  Application Register for Events.  Then when the Timer Tick runs a check which events have data and which Applications are registers for the events.When a registered event has data then the Timer Tick call the Event handler.  Windows is constantly doing task switching base on priority and application has no control on the switching.

Comment: I tried to some code to make it easier to see what happends.